# Multi-site Installation in Wordpress | Security & Future Migrations

Tags: multisite, installation

I think from just one dashboard we can install WordPress on multiple domains.

Suppose I have a website say samplesite.com and a subdomain blog.samplesite.com or - samplesite.com/blog/

**1. samplesite.com**

**2. blog.samplesite.com**

**3. samplesite.com/blog**

All of the above are possible? These multiple installations will use the same database or multiple databases?

Because in future if there are any event to migrate subdomain or something this arrangement could be an issue or not?

can these multi sites choose different themes for them?

**SECURITY ISSUES?**
Does It use the same database or multiple databases? If I wish to give admin right to soMe else would it be possible in future to give admin access to only one installation? also, my installation will have lots of user activity. Users will be given access and they will sell their products on one installation, keeping this in mind is this arrangement safe?

**FUTURE MIGRATION:** If one site needs to be migrated to some different server in future would this migration be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WordPress multi-site or "network" would fit your need exactly.  One thing to point out based on your example.  You may only choose sub domain or sub folder installation.  WP multi-site is not geared to do both by default, you must choose one or the other at setup.

The setup is surprisingly simple:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Regarding themes, yes.  Plugins and themes can be managed separately across all sites in the network.  You could easily have 2 dozen domains (or subdomains) running on a single WP multi-site, each with it's own theme and plugin set.

**Additional questions regarding security**:  Yes - each site has the ability to grant users with varying levels of access. You may also create additional "Super admin" users which can manage all sites on the network.  You can add and remove privileges for users for each site or across the network.

Safety is about much more than user access.  This arrangement does give you control over all types of user access, however.

Comment: It uses the same database or multiple databases?

Comment: All sites in the WP network use the same DB and file system.

Comment: I have added more question in the main question regarding security. one DB and so many sites, if some site needs to be migrated in future wouldn't this create issues in future?

Comment: You should ask a separate question.  This is a Q&A site, not a discussion board.

Comment: Sir that's why I have updated the question, You too please update your answer.

Comment: technically you are wrong about the users, all sites share the same users with varying levels of permissions

Comment: Correct - my answer regarding users is an over-simplification.